# Remove multiple nodes of the same value with one function execute

Tags: c++

```
void List::delete_dupes() {
for (IntNode* i = head; i != 0; i = i->next) {
    for (IntNode* curr = i; curr != 0; curr = curr->next) {
        if ((curr->next != 0) && (curr != 0)) {
            if (curr->next->data == i->data) {
                IntNode* new = curr->next->next;
                delete curr->next;
                curr->next = new;
            }
            if (curr->next == 0) {
                tail = curr;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am creating a function inside a class called "List" that, given a linked list of nodes, is supposed to delete every node that contains the same value as the node located by i, hence removing duplicate nodes.

I can run the function just fine, as it does remove the duplicate nodes, but the small problem I am running into is that I want the function to remove all the duplicate nodes in one function call, but it would only remove the first duplicate.

Comment: Maybe you want recursion. Try delete_dupes again, if no dupes were deleted, return from upper function.

Comment: At least at first glance, it looks like this shouldn't compile at all. You're attempting to create a variable named `new`, but `new` is a reserved word in C++, so you can't use it as a variable name. Therefore, `IntNode* new = curr->next->next;` should be rejected as a syntax error (and so should `curr->next = new;`)

Comment: @ChemiCalChems  I returned from the upper functions, but I am still getting the same output.

Comment: @JerryCoffin My bad ... I originally had it set as newTemp, not new. Nevertheless, my code still won't delete all dupes in one function call.

Comment: Next question: are you trying to do this in real code, or are you just playing around with linked lists for (fun | education)? If you're trying to write real code, you probably want to toss out your own `List` and use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` instead.